# How to send a POST request from a function in my Frontend JS file in my NodeJS web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, http-post

Lets say i have two variables in my NodeJS front end **Example.js** file:

```
var a;
var b;

function senddata() {

       a = "Hassan";
       b = 7;

  }
return true;
```

Now what i'd like to do is send these two variables to my server using a **POST** request. At the backend i'm using ExpressJS for my routes.

In my **Routes.js**(At the backend) i want to receive the values of a and b through a **POST** request from my **senddata()** function.

In my routes i have created this route for the data:

```
router.post('/save', function (req, res, next) {


//Sending values of a and b to my database





});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have NodeJs on the front-end too. I would suggest to use a http client, like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Then you can use it this way:

```
const axios = require('axios');

function senddata() {

  axios.post('/save', {
    a: 'Hassan',
    b: 7
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
}
```